# Creating a checkers board in python

Tags: python-3.x

It's currently between semesters and I wanted to do a second "final project" for nothing other than practice. I decided to make a checkers game in python.

I'm using the graphics library to do this in. The way I want it to work is to build the board using squares and I want to label each of them as their own entity. I don't know if this can work*** but I want to create a dictionary to store each rectangle and have a value to show if there is a piece there or not. So far this is what I have to build the board....

```
    def board(win,coordSys):
        xRange = 'ABCDEFGH'
        X = 0
        for x in range(1,9):
            for y in range(1,9):
                Rec = Rectangle(Point(x,y),Point(x+1,y+1))

                if x%2 == 0 and y%2 == 0:
                    Rec.setFill('red')
                    coordSys[xRange[X]+str(y)] = 0
                elif x%2 != 0 and y%2 != 0 :
                    Rec.setFill('red')
                    coordSys[xRange[X]+str(y)] = 0
                else:
                    Rec.setFill('grey')

                Rec.draw(win)
            X+=1
```

I'm relatively new at Python so i'm trying to do it with the tools that I'm already aware of for now. My question is, how can I store individual rectangles using a A1-H8 format in a dictionary so that I can have {A1:0 etc..} and I'm able to check the value of A1 to see if anything has been altered in A1's rectangle?

Comment: haven't you done that already?

Comment: It creates a dictionary with the correct coordinates, but there is no coorelation between the coordinate and the square. If I were to try and call for example A1, it's just a string, and doesn't point to square A1

Comment: `coordSys[xRange[X]+str(y)] = Rec`?

Comment: What in the world is "the graphics library"?  You don't seriously believe that there's only one, do you?

Comment: Didn't mean to offend you Jason....it's the graphics library most commonly used in my textbook. "Python programming - John Zelle"

Comment: You gave me an idea mic4ael, thank you! I'll do one dictionary to keep track of the rectangles, and another to keep track of if a piece is on the square or not.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is a dictionary whose values are the rectangles in question, it sounds like what you are looking for is something like

```
for x in range(1, 9):
    for y in range(1, 9):
        rec = Rectangle(Point(x, y), Point(x+1, y+1))
        coordSys[xRange[x-1] + str(y)] = rec
        rec.draw(win)
```

Comment: Would I then have to use a second dictionary to associate each of those rectangles in the dictionary to a value of either 0,1, or 2. Every square that has a 1 has a black piece on it, every 2 has a red etc...I don't know if that makes sense. Let me know if not and i'll try and clarify.